# Can a rigid-prop quadcopter hover upside-down?

Tags: motor, quadcopter, multi-rotor

Most small quadcopters use rigid rotors with some fixed pitch.
In principle, I can imagine it might be possible for such a rigid-prop quadcopter to hover upside-down,
but that apparently requires reversing the direction of rotation of all 4 motors.

(This is very different from the way some "standard" single-rotor model helicopters can hover upside-down by continuing to spin that rotor in "the same direction", but moving the swash plate to give negative blade pitch).

Is it possible for a rigid-prop quadcopter to hover upside-down?

When I build a quadcopter so it can switch from flying upright to flying upside-down and back again in mid-flight, what do I do differently than a normal quadcopter designed to always fly right-side-up?

(Related: ["Can you run a BLDC motor backwards without damage?"](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/2771/can-you-run-a-bldc-motor-backwards-without-damage) )

Answer (score 2):

You can run a brushless DC motors backwards using a [H-bridge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/H_bridge). Basically you'll need to program your microcontroller/microprocessor onboard to flip the polarity of 2 of the wires of the bldc (a bldc has 3 wires, switching any 2 wires will reverse the spin)